# Google cloud storage parallel upload java

Tags: java, upload, google-cloud-storage

I have some big files that I want to upload to cloud storage. I want to use parallel upload to save time. 
I found this lib: gsutil but I can't find any java example or usage 
only for python.

Comment: Please try to improve your question as much as you can. Did you try something?

Answer (score 1):

gsutil is not distributed as a library, only as a command-line tool. I don't know of a Java library that supports parallel uploads, though that doesn't mean there isn't one. However, you could do parallel writes by using the Compose operation, using the JSON or XML API for Google Cloud Storage. Specifically, you would write a number of smaller objects in parallel and then (once all of those objects have been written) call the Compose request to compose them into one larger object. If you're using the JSON API the compose documentation is at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/compose
If you're using the XML API the compose documentation is at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference-methods#putobject (see the compose query parameter).